# A view after an scale animation, have not resize to new position

Tags: android, animation

A view after an scale animation, have not resize to new position.

I using a android animation (ScaleAnimation) to make a layout(screen size when start) scale to 0.95 times size by itself and the scale reference the screen central point.

```
final AnimationListener al2 = new AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {

    }
};
public void animScale(){
    ScaleAnimation sa = new ScaleAnimation(1,0.95f,1,0.95f, topLayout.getMeasuredWidth()/2, topLayout.getMeasuredHeight()/2);
    sa.setDuration(500);
    sa.setFillEnabled(true);
    sa.setFillAfter(true);
    sa.setAnimationListener(al2);
    topLayout.startAnimation(sa);

}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   

    scaleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scaleButton);
    scaleButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            animScale();
        }
    });
}
```

after this animation my layout have been changed to new position, but when i click again the button

the layout always from screen size scale to 0.95 times.

that show me the layout never change the actual size through the animation.

what code i need to add in the animation listener animation end?

i hope to achieve when i click the button it will do that,
 screen size -> screen size *0.95 -> screen size *0.95^2 ->........

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because you are using `Animation` class. With Animation you only change the visible appearance.
In your case you need to use `Animator` which also updates positions and dimensions.

The difference between Animation and Animator is explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28220613/4560619).

Answer (score 0):

ScaleAnimation doesn't changes layout's parameters. It animates without changing parameters for a smoother animation.

You can create a Boolean instance variable

```
Boolean animationDone = false;
```

and set it to true in `onAnimationEnd` to indicate if the animation is done

```
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
   animationDone=true;
}
```

and check it in animScale before animating to prevent multiple animations....

```
public void animScale(){
 if ( animationDone ) return;
  //..... animation code here...
 }
```