# What is the difference between the animator class and animation class in android?

Tags: android, animation

I was wondering what is the difference between the animation and animator class in android.

If I use the animation class to animate a FragmentTransaction.replace() by using a fade-in and fade-out animation, it causes an error and crashes the app,

```
ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,android.R.anim.fade_out);
```

but when I use the animator class

```
ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
```

It works perfectly fine.

It seems to me that the animator class is newer, and the animation class is older, but when should one use the animator or animation class?

Comment: Your question already have an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220613/what-is-the-difference-between-an-animator-and-an-animation .

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that.