# Wrong coordinates after TranslateAnimation

Tags: java, android, animation, webview, android-animation

The resolution of my device is `1080*1920 (portrait)`, and the size of my webview is `1080*960`

I use TranslateAnimation on WebView to translate it `from y=0 to y=960`.

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0f, 0f, 0f, 960f);
animation.setDuration(300);
animation.setFillAfter(true);

webview.startAnimation(animation);
```

Android help me to draw the webview to y=960, but I cannot trigger any touch event in the `y range [960, 1920]`, instead, my touch event is triggered in the `y range [0, 960]`.

It seems some control component or other things didn't be translated to y=960 with the webview.

Is there any method to translate the control also to y=960, or other better solution is recommended?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TranslateAnimation` animates the matrix, not the `View` itself. So, you end up seeing an illusion: you see a `View` which in fact has other coordinates.

Either you need to change `WebView` coordinates after animation ends, or you can use fluent API instead of `TranslateAnimation`:

```
webview.animate()
       .y(960f)
       .setDuration(300);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Also, the thread [What is the difference between an Animator and an Animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220613/what-is-the-difference-between-an-animator-and-an-animation) is helpful to me, too.